# Are temporaries const? Pass by const reference

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, pass-by-const-reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(const int& x)
{
}

int g()
{
    int x = 0;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    f(g());
}
```

If i remove the const from f it doesnt work;
What does this mean, is the temporary returned from g a const???

Comment: A parameter of `const int&` says "take the parameter by reference, and I promise not to modify it".  `int&` says "take the parameter by reference, and I'll be modifying it".  It doesn't make sense to *modify* a temporary — that could only lead to subtle programming bugs, which is why it isn't allowed.

Comment: Nitpick before I finish looking into it: why `using namespace std;`? Nothing from `std` is even used here, and there's a litany of reasons to avoid it. See [Why is using namespace std considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Note that you can however declare `void f(int&& x)` (since C++11). This is a *rvalue reference*, used in the **move** semantics. This is advanced feature however, that a beginner should not worry about yet.

Comment: @Eljay -- the issue is more subtle; temporaries of class types can be modified (but still can't be passed by non-const reference). So `struct X { void modify_me(); }; X f() { return X(); }; f().modify_me();` is okay.